# NDSolveValue in NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions, finite-element-method

I would like to implement a sort of Euler explicit manually. I have this code

```
alpha=1
a = 9/4
SOL[R_] = NDSolveValue[{-alpha * (-2 + 12*a*f[x]^2)*Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z}, 
  "Spherical"] == 
  (Max[1 + (R - l)/l*(1 - R/x), 0] - 0.5), f[R] == 2/3, 
   f'[0.00001] == 0.000001}, f, {x, 0.0001, R}] 


v[x_]=-(1-SOL[R][x])(-2+12*9/4*SOL[R][x]^2)SOL[R]'[x]
```

Now, I would like to take a $R(t=0)=R_0$, and write $R(t+\Delta t)=R(t)+v(R)\Delta t$, in order to have a numerical function $R(t)$.

What I tried is to write an equation on $R$, and to enter the NDSolveValue in another NDSolveValue :

```
  alpha = 1
  a = 9/4

  SOL[R_] := NDSolveValue[{-alpha * (-2 + 12*a*f[x]^2)*Laplacian[f[x], 
{x, y, z}, "Spherical"] == (Min[Max[1 + (R - l)/l*(1 - R/x), 0], 1] - 0.5),
f[R] == 2/3, f'[0.00001] == 0.000001}, f, {x, 0.0001, R}]

    radius = NDSolveValue[{g'[t] == - SOL[g[t]][g[t] - 0.001] (1 - 
SOL[g[t]][g[t] - 0.001]) (-2 +  12*a*SOL[g[t]][g[t] - 0.001]^2) SOL[g[t]]'[g[t] - 0.0001], 
g[0] == 0.5}, g, {t, 0, 2}, MaxSteps -> 10^2]
```

But I get the message *NDSolveValue::derarg: The derivative operator Derivative[1]     in (NDSolveValue[{-(-2+27 Power[<<2>>]) (2 Power[<<2>>] (<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]+(f^[Prime][Prime])[x])==-0.5+Min[1,Max[0,Plus[<<2>>]]],f[g[t]]==2/3,(f^[Prime])[0.00001]==1.*10^-6},f,{x,0.0001,g[t]}]^[Prime])[-0.0001+g[t]]    should act on the pure function.*

Do you have an idea how to proceed ?

Comment: What is the differential equation that you want to solve? It's not clear because you use `Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z},   "Spherical"]` which confuses me because `f` has only a single scalar argument.

Comment: Since I choose a spherical symmetry, ' f ' has only one argument, _r_ the radius, which is in the code ' x ' . I have two differential equations : one that gives me _f_ in function of _x_, and one that gives me _R_ in function of _t_. the first one is esay to solve with NDSolveValue, and the second one is connected to the first one  of _f_  which is _v_, and through a "boundary condition" : ' f(R)=2/3 '. And eventually I want to solve the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alpha = 1; a = 9/4; l = .001;

SOL = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-alpha*(-2 + 12*a*f[x]^2)*
     Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"]/
      R^2 == (Min[Max[1 + (R - l)/l*(1 - 1/x), 0], 1] - 0.5), 
   f[1] == 2/3, f'[0.00001] == 0.000001}, f, {x, 0.0001, 1}, {R}]
    SOL1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-alpha*(-2 + 12*a*f[x]^2)*
     Laplacian[f[x], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"]/
      R^2 == (Min[Max[1 + (R - l)/l*(1 - 1/x), 0], 1] - 0.5), 
   f[1] == 2/3, f'[0.00001] == 0.000001}, f', {x, 0.0001, 1}, {R}]
radius = NDSolveValue[{g'[
     t] == -SOL[g[t]][(g[t] - 0.001)/g[t]] (1 - 
       SOL[g[t]][(g[t] - 0.001)/g[t]]) (-2 + 
       12*a*SOL[g[t]][(g[t] - 0.001)/g[t]]^2) SOL1[
        g[t]][(g[t] - 0.001)/g[t]]/g[t], g[0] == 0.5}, g, {t, 0, 2}]
Plot[radius[t], {t, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "R"}]
```

[image: fig 1]